# Выполнение js функции в течение 10 секунд

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Подскажите способ, чтобы функция выполнялась не одномоментно, а в течение 10 секунд.

Есть функция js

```
function move() {
        var barSize = $this.children('button').outerWidth();
        var progressBar = $this.children('.fill');
        var width = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
            if(width >=100){
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                progressBar.css( "width", width+'%');
            }
        }
 }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы она выполнялась в течение 10 секунд, а не сразу или по разу каждую секунду, поэтому (`setTimeout`) не подходит.

Comment: сделайте чтобы она выполнялась раз в 50мс, а потом остановите ее выполнение через 10секунд, либо таймаутом, либо считайте сколько времени прошло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var start = performance.now();

var animaTime = 10; // Время анимации в секундах
var FPS = 60;       // "кадры" (вызовы функции) в секунду

var width = 0;
var limit = id('progress').clientWidth;
var bar = id('bar');

var updateRate = 1000/FPS;
var updateStep = (limit/FPS) / animaTime;

var interval = setInterval(animaProgress, updateRate);

function animaProgress() {
  if (width >= limit) {
    bar.style.width = limit;
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log( "Прошло (ms):", performance.now() - start );
    
    return;
  }
  
  width += updateStep;
  bar.style.width = width + "px";
}

function id(str) { return document.getElementById(str); }
```

```css
#progress {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#bar {
  position: asolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
  <div id="bar"></div> 
</div>
```

Выходит небольшое отставание из-за деления 1000/60... Можно сделать 100 вызовов в секунду, чтобы кругленько встало на место за 10 секунд.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var $this = $();
function move() {
  var barSize = $this.children('button').outerWidth();
  var progressBar = $this.children('.fill');
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 100);

  function frame() {
    console.clear();
    console.log('width =', width);
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      progressBar.css("width", width + '%');
    }
  }
}
move();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```